# What is the equivalent of script/destroy scaffold User in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I was using Rails 2, I did `script/generate scaffold User` to create the user model. Now I need to remove it, and I'm using Rails 3. I tried `rails destroy scaffold User` and `rails destroy User`, but these just created new rails projects named destroy. How do I do it? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you are not running an older rails version at the time? Maybe forgot to switch to your Rails3 gemset with RVM?

It works fine here and this is the rails help output:

```
In addition to those, there are:
 application  Generate the Rails application code
 destroy      Undo code generated with "generate"
```

Comment: That was it, boy do I feel stupid. Just wondering, what's the command to get the rails help output? I'm new to terminal. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use rails or rails --help in a rails3 directory, you can also check a lot of other stuff this way, try using rails g(enerate) to see every generator for example :)